# Showing a column from a cursor in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have implemented a database in sqlite that has one table.I have already coded the data retreival methods.But after I have retrieved a column and stored it in cursor,How to show that column in a list-view or listactivity

Comment: Get that column data from cursor and put in array and this array set with adapter and set this adapter with list view.

Comment: You have to use something called Adapter to show the data in the `ListView`... tell us if you are not familiar with adapters. Or show your adapter code.

Comment: if you not familiar with adapter see the link http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this sample code:

Get the column data in ArraryList:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data= // get your column data here
```

Then set Array Adapter class:

```
public class ListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private ListView listView;

    public GalleryListArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list, ListView listView) {
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_list_item, list);

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listView = listView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int pos = position;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_item, parent, false);
        return rowView; 
    }
}
```